# Generate one dataframe per element in a column and merge into current dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following (example) dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path

cwd = Path('Path/to/somewhere')
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'var1': [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
        'var2': ['A', 'B']*3,
        'var3': ['A', 'B']*3,
        'path_col': [cwd / 'a.dat', cwd / 'b.dat', cwd / 'c.dat', cwd / 'd.dat', cwd / 'e.dat', cwd / 'f.dat'],
    }
 )
```

Each path in `path_col` points to a datafile, which I have a function to convert into a dataframe, e.g. :

```
def open_and_convert_to_df(filepath: pathlib.Path):
    # do things
    return pd.Dataframe(...)
```

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'var4': [10, 20, 30],
        'var5': [100, 200, 300],
        'obs': [1000, 2000, 3000],
    }
)
```

I'd like to generate a data_df from each path in `path_col` and merge into `df` such that the final df looks like :

```
    var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 obs
0   0    A    1    10   100  1000
1   0    A    1    10   100  2000
2   0    A    1    10   100  3000
3   0    A    1    10   200  1000
4   0    A    1    10   200  2000
5   0    A    1    10   200  3000
6   0    A    1    10   300  1000
...
n-3 25   B    2    30   200  3000
n-2 25   B    2    30   300  1000
n-1 25   B    2    30   300  2000
n   25   B    2    30   300  3000
```

In other words, variables 1 to 3 of the first df are indexes of the data contained in `path_col`.
Inside this data, var 4 and 5 are indexes of `obs`. I'm trying to index `obs` with all variables from 1 to 5.

The best I've come up with so far is using the `.map()` method like so :

```
df['path_col'] = df['path_col'].map(open_and_convert_to_df)
```

I end up with the right df's in each `path_col` element but I'm lacking the next steps in order to "un-nest" those and obtain the desired df.

Comment: the initial `df` is incorrect, it throws `ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`

Comment: My bad, fixed it using mozway's answer

Comment: @MaximGi and did my approach work? Can you provide a dummy example of some of the files and the exact expected output for clarity?

Comment: Tested just now, it worked, see my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want some kind of [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or each row with the output of the function, you could use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = df.join(pd.concat({k: open_and_convert_to_df(v)
                         for k,v in df['path_col'].items()}
                        ).droplevel(1))
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'var1': [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
        'var2': ['A', 'B']*3,
        'var3': [1, 2]*3,
        'path_col': [cwd / 'a.dat', cwd / 'b.dat', cwd / 'c.dat', cwd / 'd.dat', cwd / 'e.dat', cwd / 'f.dat'],
    }
 )
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. The resulting dataframe (out) index may be properly reset in the next step : `out.reset_index(drop=True)`. Thanks